# On the right track with code wars question, but things are going sideways somewhere

Tags: javascript

I am working on a code wars question and feel like I'm on the right track, but things are going sideways somewhere in the code. Can some one point out to me where the logic is failing?

Here's my code:

```
function incrementString (strng) {
  let numbs = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];
  let holdingPen = [];
  let pigPen = [];  
  //turn string into array
  strng = strng.split("")
  
  //use a for loop to find all the numbers
  for (let i = 0; i < strng.length; i++){
      //put the numbers into a holding pen
    if (strng[i] == numbs || strng[i] == "0"){
      holdingPen.push(strng[i]);
      //remove numbers from string
      strng.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  
  for (let j = 0; j < holdingPen.length; j++){
      //if index of 0 is before index of 123456789
  if (holdingPen.indexOf(0) < numbs.indexOf(strng[j])) {
      //push numbers to pigPen where they will hangout until everything is joined together
      pigPen.push(holdingPen[j])
      holdingPen.splice(j, 1);
    }
  }
    
  //join holdingPen and parseInt
  holdingPen = parseInt(holdingPen.join(''))
  
  //add 1
  //make newNum into an array
  let newNum = holdingPen + 1
  
  newNum = newNum.toString().split("")
  
  
  //see if the integer length increased by 1, if yes subract a 0 if there was any before it
if (newNum.length > holdingPen.toString().length) {
    pigPen.shift()
  }
    
  //join strng and holdingPen
  let result = strng.concat(pigPen, newNum)
  
  return result.join('').toString()
  
 
}
```

Here's the question:
Your job is to write a function which increments a string, to create a new string.

- If the string already ends with a number, the number should be incremented by 1.
- If the string does not end with a number. the number 1 should be appended to the new string.

Examples:

`foo -> foo1`

`foobar23 -> foobar24`

I noted the psuedo code along with the code

Comment: `if (strng[i] == numbs...` will never be true. you are comparing a string and an array. This seems like a good opportunity to learn how to add breakpoints and logging to debug your code.

Comment: Use a regular expression to get the number at the end of the string: `/\d+$/`

Comment: JSYK, `.join` always returns a string, so there's no need to call `toString()` on that.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues; the main one would be the logic of your code (extremely roundabout and prone to bugs, e.g. trying to find all the numbers in the string instead of just the last one, making literally everything an array, etc.), which I won't go into because there are better approaches. The other issues:

- You're comparing a single character to an array of characters (change to `numbs.includes(strng[i])` instead)
- `indexOf` doesn't coerce types, so it's `indexOf("0")`, not `indexOf(0)`

Using regular expressions makes it simple (you don't need regex, but it'll be just a bit more verbose):

```js
function solution(str) {
  // if the string ends in a number
  if(/\d$/.test(str))
    // increment
    return str.replace(/\d+$/, n => ++n)
  return str + 1 // otherwise just append "1"
}

console.log(solution("foo"))
console.log(solution("foobar23"))
```

And as always, the one-liner for those who need it:

```js
const solution = str => /\d$/.test(str) ? str.replace(/\d+$/, n => ++n) : str + 1
```